# Given canonical coordinates, difficulty understanding use of poisson bracket identities to find transformation function

Tags: transformation, jacobian, canonical-transformation

Given that $(q,p)$ are canonical coordinates, determine the function $f$ such that the transformation

$$
Q=f(q)\cos{p}, \quad P=f(q)\sin{p} 
$$

is canonical

---

I have made good progress using the Jacobian characterisation method to calculate a solution but Im having trouble understanding the solution using poisson bracket calculations

The solution starts with

\begin{align}
\{ Q, P\} 
&= \{ f(q)\cos{p},f(q)\sin{p} \} \\
&=f(q)\sin{p}\{\cos{p},f(q)\}+f(q)\cos{p}\{f(q),\sin{p}\} \\
&=-f(q)f'(q)\sin^2{p}\{p,q\}+f(q)f'(q)\cos^2{p}\{q,p\}\\
&=\;...
\end{align}

**How do we go from the first line to the second line**?

It doesn't seem to fall into the fundamental properties of the poisson bracket as far as I can see.